# How does NLTK's classifier transform the large amount of features to train the model?

Tags: python, classification, nltk, dimensionality-reduction

In the documentation examples (chapter 6, 1.3), they selected the top 2000 words in the training set as features and the data set is 2000 rows long. If it was trained with all 2000 words as columns and 2000 rows, it wouldn't be able to find any patterns due to the curse of dimensionality. But it works and works really great. So I checked the source and found the code below, which just didn't make any sense to me.

To me it looks like they are mapping the frequency of words to a probability for each label. But this is supposed to be a Naive Bayes algorithm. How is this being trained?

```
 def train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator=ELEProbDist):
    """
    :param labeled_featuresets: A list of classified featuresets,
        i.e., a list of tuples ``(featureset, label)``.
    """
    label_freqdist = FreqDist()
    feature_freqdist = defaultdict(FreqDist)
    feature_values = defaultdict(set)
    fnames = set()

    # Count up how many times each feature value occurred, given
    # the label and featurename.
    for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
        label_freqdist[label] += 1
        for fname, fval in featureset.items():
            # Increment freq(fval|label, fname)
            feature_freqdist[label, fname][fval] += 1
            # Record that fname can take the value fval.
            feature_values[fname].add(fval)
            # Keep a list of all feature names.
            fnames.add(fname)

    # If a feature didn't have a value given for an instance, then
    # we assume that it gets the implicit value 'None.'  This loop
    # counts up the number of 'missing' feature values for each
    # (label,fname) pair, and increments the count of the fval
    # 'None' by that amount.
    for label in label_freqdist:
        num_samples = label_freqdist[label]
        for fname in fnames:
            count = feature_freqdist[label, fname].N()
            # Only add a None key when necessary, i.e. if there are
            # any samples with feature 'fname' missing.
            if num_samples - count > 0:
                feature_freqdist[label, fname][None] += num_samples - count
                feature_values[fname].add(None)

    # Create the P(label) distribution
    label_probdist = estimator(label_freqdist)

    # Create the P(fval|label, fname) distribution
    feature_probdist = {}
    for ((label, fname), freqdist) in feature_freqdist.items():
        probdist = estimator(freqdist, bins=len(feature_values[fname]))
        feature_probdist[label, fname] = probdist

    return cls(label_probdist, feature_probdist)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Naive Bayes algorithm does not do any feature selection. I don't know what "patterns" you are imagining when you write that "it wouldn't be able to find any patterns due to the curse of dimensionality," but it does indeed use all the supplied features in its model.

The label probabilities are estimated by combining the probability estimates from each individual feature, **as if the features were mutually statistically independent** (that is the "naive" part of the model). This makes it very fast and easy to construct a Naive Bayes probability model. Features that have more predictive power (more strongly associated with one of the outcome labels) have more impact on the computed probability. Features that can occur with any label with approximately equal probability have negligible impact on the estimate.

Perhaps you meant that if a word that only occurs in one training document, it will be spuriously associated with that document's label? This is true, but it can only cause problems if that word occurs in a document being classified. Most of the time, the more widespread words will determine the probability estimates.